# How to express this truth set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How would you express this truth set in mathematical terms?

$4 < x^2 \le 9, X \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: welcome to [MATHEMATICS](http://math.stackexchange.com/) Use [MathJax Help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to have a clearer question, please.

Comment: I think you're asking more about "how to *simplify* this truth set", since you've already *expressed* it in mathematical terms (more or less).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 2 < x \leq 3 \text{ or } -3 \leq x < -2\},$ also known as $(2,3] \cup [-3,-2)$ (since taking square roots over $\mathbb{R}^+$ preserves inequalities; but be careful with negative real numbers and $n$'th roots when $n$ is even).

Comment: Thank you. If you were to reduce the 4 and 9, to, say 1 and 3, would you be able to express roots in your formal answer? {x∈R∣1<x≤root3}

Comment: I mean this just in general, I'm wondering if roots are acceptable in the notation, as in <= root(7) for example. Because it's very easy to find the truth set involved, but the notation is the part that confuses me.

Comment: Sure, in case we had 1 and 3, then the set would be $\{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 1 < x \leq \sqrt{3}\}.$

Comment: What about $\left[-3,-2\right)$?

Comment: Right; @user3308043 I forgot to add the negative part!

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 Thanks for pointing it out; I didn't realize we were working over all the reals.

Comment: oh yes... great point.